# TypeScript: one-liner syntax to re-export typeof a module

Tags: typescript

For lack of terms, I'm not sure how to better describe my problem. Basically I want to re-export all the exported items' type from a module, under a namespace. I am able to do it in 2 lines.

```
import type * as api from './api'
export type API = typeof api
```

Is there a one-liner equivalent to ditch the intermediate variable `api`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, the one-liner syntax is:

```
export type API = typeof import('./api')
```